# What URL is needed to be sent in the Cloudrail AdvancedRequestSpecification to get the LinkedIn Experience or Education profile sections?

Tags: xamarin, cloudrail

I implemented the Login with LinkedIn Social Sample, and successfully got back the Id, Name, Email, Gender, PictureUrl, Description and BirthDate using the [Github Cloudrail-Xamarin](https://github.com/CloudRail/cloudrail-si-xamarin-android-sdk) example.

The [documentation](https://blog.cloudrail.com/access-all-api-features-with-cloudrails-advanced-request/) suggests to use the AdvancedRequestSpecification feature to request the “Education” or “Experience” sections of the LinkedIn profile. But only gives a dropbox example.

What URL is needed to be sent in the AdvancedRequestSpecification(“url goes here”) to get the “Education” or “Experience” sections of the LinkedIn profile?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it should be the same URL but you need to apply for the "Apply with LinkedIn program" to get the full response. Here is a list of all the available fields: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields